# python3 pyipmi connect

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет.
Подскажите , как сделать лучше, есть код:

```
import pyipmi
from pyipmi.interfaces import INTERFACES

from config import HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWD


interface = pyipmi.interfaces.create_interface(interface='rmcp',
                                             slave_address=0x81,
                                             host_target_address=0x20,
                                             keep_alive_interval=1)
ipmi = pyipmi.create_connection(interface)
ipmi.session.set_session_type_rmcp(host='10.0.114.199', port=623)
ipmi.session.set_auth_type_user(username=USERNAME, password=PASSWD)
ipmi.target = pyipmi.Target(ipmb_address=0x20)
ipmi.session.establish()

device_id = ipmi.get_device_id()

ipmpi.session.close()
```

как лучше написать функцию чтобы вместо

> device_id = ipmi.get_device_id()

подсунуть другие функции , например :

> power_stat = ipmi.get_chassis_status().power_on

или любую другую(их много).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно то, о чём вы спросили, можно сделать так:

```
vars = {
    'device_id': ipmi.get_device_id(),
    'power_stat': ipmi.get_chassis_status().power_on,
}

def call_func(name):
    globals()[name] = vars[name]


call_func('power_stat')
```

Но вообще, динамическое создание переменных - это скользкий путь, и обычно можно обойтись без него. Раз у вас всё-равно будет словарь vars из которого любое нужное значение можно получить по ключу, то создавать переменные и необязательно - просто обращайтесь к словарю по ключу, всюду, где вы бы использовали переменную.